# Failed to sync Gradle project 'dsploit' (Android Studio 0.8.11)

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to compile dSploit (an Android app) using Android Studio 0.8.11.

But, when trying to compile I get this error:

```
Error:Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+.
Required by:
dSploit:dSploit:unspecified
Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
```

I don't see any Android Support Repositories available in the Android SDK manager.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have to update your sdk build tools!

Comment: Android suppor repositories is under the Extras tab in SDK manager. Download it from there.